# How to access httpd.conf in Docker from a php image that included apache by itself?

Tags: php, apache, docker, httpconfiguration

**Problem**

I'm able to find the **httpd.conf** when I run a container from the **[httpd](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd)** image, but I can't find that file when I run the container from a PHP image that includes apache, like the image **php:7.4.2-apache-buster**

The php image was ran this way, also **$(pwd)** is pointing to the proyect directory

```
docker container run -d -p 80:80 \
--name containerName \
-v $(pwd):/var/www/html \
php:7.4.2-apache-buster
```

---

**Tried**

I used `docker container exec -it normalApache bash` in the **normal httpd image**, in which I was able to find the **httpd.conf** file in **/usr/local/apache2/conf**

But when I try to do the exact same thing in the apache included with the php image, I can't find that file because the directory **apache2** in **/usr/local** doesn't even exit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever you are looking for, the `Dockerfile` for that container can be found at https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/703a3d0a4e4c149bfd62fc3e7b71645f9496b178/7.4/buster/apache/Dockerfile, and in line 52 it uses `/etc/apache2` as the configuration directory

```
51 ##<autogenerated>##
52 ENV APACHE_CONFDIR /etc/apache2
53 ENV APACHE_ENVVARS $APACHE_CONFDIR/envvars
```

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Comment: @NicoHaase I added a line to enable mod_rewrite, but now the container doesn't even start and therefore I can't access bash to remove the line

Comment: Then remove the line and start it.

Comment: "Doesn't even start" sounds strange. Is there any error message given? If yes, open a new question for it :)